# split complex mysql select by date

Tags: mysql, date, select, sql-order-by, pivot

I have this MySQL SELECT of a table creating a pivot.

```
SELECT t.*,
   sum(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(Arbeitsbeginn, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s'),
   STR_TO_DATE(Arbeitsende, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')))) AS ARBEITSZEIT,
   sum(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(Projektbeginn, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s'), 
                     STR_TO_DATE(Projektende, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')))) AS Projektzeit
FROM (SELECT DriverName,
         Baustelle,
         Arbeitsbeginn,
         Arbeitsende,
         Projektbeginn,
         Projektende
  FROM (SELECT DRIVERNAME,
               GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'PB', AREA, NULL)) AS 'Baustelle',
               GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'Arbeitsbeginn', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Arbeitsbeginn',
               GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'Arbeitsende', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Arbeitsende',
               GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'PB', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Projektbeginn',
               GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'PE', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Projektende'
        FROM geoImportRoot
        GROUP BY DRIVERNAME
       ) A CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 2) n
) t
GROUP BY DriverName;
```

CHECK THIS FIDDLE: [SELECT](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bcf5/1)

The Problem is, that I need the data sepereted by date, at the moment i get them all in a row:

> 19.06.2013 09:09:01,19.06.2013 10:29:28,19.06.2013 14:01:11,20.06.2013 10:01:00

Hope you can help me fixing this. If possible, use SQL Fiddle

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "separated by date"? I've looked at your SQLFiddle output. Can you show what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't store date/time values as character strings.  You should use in the built-in data type for that purpose.

In any case, the data is the first 10 characters of the string.  The following variation splits the data by day:

```
SELECT t.*,
  sum(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(Arbeitsbeginn, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s'), STR_TO_DATE(Arbeitsende, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')))) AS ARBEITSZEIT,
  sum(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(Projektbeginn, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s'), STR_TO_DATE(Projektende, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')))) AS Projektzeit
FROM (SELECT DriverName, thedate,
             Baustelle,
             Arbeitsbeginn,
             Arbeitsende,
             Projektbeginn,
             Projektende

      FROM (SELECT DRIVERNAME, left(`datetime`, 10) as thedate,
                   GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'PB', AREA, NULL)) AS 'Baustelle',
                   GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'Arbeitsbeginn', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Arbeitsbeginn',
                   GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'Arbeitsende', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Arbeitsende',
                   GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'PB', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Projektbeginn',
                   GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'PE', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Projektende'
            FROM geoImportRoot
            GROUP BY DRIVERNAME, left(`datetime`, 12)
           ) A CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 2) n
    ) t
GROUP BY DriverName, thedate;
```